# How many restrictions needed to test a cointegration relation if r = 4?

Tags: r, regression, var, ecm

I estimated a VECM with five I(1)-Variables that are cointegrated. The test results in four cointegrating equations. Now I want to identify all cointegrating vectors and my question is: How many restrictions do I need to impose at minimum and how can I execute an LR-test using the VECM() function?

```
VECM1 = VECM(vardata1,lag=0, r=4, estim = c("ML"),exogen = M,include = "none")

H=matrix(byrow=T,c(1,0,0,0,0,
                   1,1,0,0,0,
                   0,0,1,0,0,
                   0,0,1,1,0,
                   0,0,1,0,1))
```

Sadly `blrtest(VECM1,H=H,r=3)` only works for ca.jo objects. But with `ca.jo()` a VECM can only be estimated with a minimum VAR lag order of 2 (I have 1).